# Only Load required js scripts on particular page

Tags: magento2, javascript

Hi we have a custom theme where i have examined that only 16 js files are required on that page but the magento loads up 298 scripts which slows the home page speed.

so i want to know is there a way to stop loading those extra scripts and loads only that is required over the particular page. did anyone tried that

**UPDATE:- AM TRYING TO STOP ADAPTER.JS FROM LOADING WHICH IS A MAGENTO LUMA JS**

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
       <remove src="adapter.js"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

[image]

Comment: Have you found how you added those script? Currently you have added those into default.xml file.

Comment: no i have not added those scripts those are automatically laoded up when page laods up is it becasue the custom theme is a child of luma? could this be a reason for this?

Comment: Kindly check on luma theme that will added on default section that why it load on all the pages, if you want that one particular pages then you can added into particular xml file only.

Comment: is it possible to stop magento luma theme js from loading on the forntend am trying it like this but it seems not working am updating the default_head_block code